# Correct Definition of Absolute Electrode Potential

Tags: electrochemistry, solid-state-chemistry

I thought absolute electrode potential is Galvani potential difference at the interface. However, it is given by following equation in John Bockris - Modern Electrochemistry (Ref.1): $$ E^M \mathrm{(abs)} = \Delta^M_S\phi -  \frac{\mu_e^M}{F} $$

First term is Galvani potential difference on the metal/solution interface and the other is chemical potential of electrons in the metal divided by Farady's constant.

**Question 1:** Why is chemical potential of electrons in metal included in the definition?

On the other hand, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_electrode_potential), absolute electrode potential is defined as: $$E^M \mathrm{(abs)} = \Delta^M_S\psi  + \phi^M  $$

Where second term is work function of the metal. This definiton is a little bit different than in Ref.1 since work function includes surface potential difference on the interface in addition to chemical potential of electrons in the metal.

**Question 2:** Why are these two definitions different?

---

**Reference**

1. John O’M. Bockris and Amulya K. N. Reddy, In *Modern Electrochemistry: An Introduction to an Interdisciplinary Area, Volume 2*; Plenum Press: New York, NY, 1970 (ISBN: 978-1-4615-8600-5).

Comment: Please look at the equations I edited are the one you meant to say. Also, see the reference 1 whether it is the correct edition you got the equation.

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn't add references on reference list. Thank you. Your edits of equations are correct, I just used notation which came to me since I think it is not too important.